# How to do textChanged event in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textchanged

I've been fixing the textChanged like event for my datagridview but I was not able to get the result that I wanted. The dataGridView1 must filter the content of dataGridView2 whenever I changed a text on its cell/s.

This can filter the content of my dataGridView2 but before that I must click the cursor outside the dataGridView1/press Tab. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit


        Dim con1 As OleDbConnection = con
        con1.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim _command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        _command.Connection = con1
        _command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE " & likeContent & ""

        dt.Load(_command.ExecuteReader)


        Me.dgv.DataSource = dt

        con1.Close()


End Sub
```

"likecontent" is where I store the text on my dataGridView1.

How will my dataGridView2 be updated just by textChanged like event from my dataGridView1?

Comment: check [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about CellValueChanged event, that will explain why you need to listen to [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the `CellValueChangedEvent` and the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` events for this.

```
 Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValueChanged
   Dim con1 As OleDbConnection = con
    con1.Open()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim _command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    _command.Connection = con1
    _command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE " & likeContent & ""

    dt.Load(_command.ExecuteReader)


    Me.dgv.DataSource = dt

    con1.Close()
 End Sub

 Private Sub dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
  If dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
    dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
  End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Mr CodeXer. Now it works! I replace "dgv" into "dataGridView1"  (except 'Me.dgv.DataSource = dt' ) because it is where the event happens.