# Can't update back color of row when boolean field is clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a datagrid which contains a boolean field. When I test the program and click a row's checkbox, it can't change back color of the row immediately, as my code has an event "CellEndEdit", I have to leave the cell to change the color. I tried some other events however couldn't make them work.

How can I change row's back color when the checkbox on datagrid is clicked?

**EDIT:** This is a Windows Forms application (not WPF) and I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. By the way, it isn't a datagrid, it's a datagridview which is populated from an mdb database.

Comment: See my answer here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842662/how-to-do-textchanged-event-in-datagridview/21842782#21842782

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. +1 to this answer and the link.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
     CheckBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255)
End If
```

You could also do something like this.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CType(sender, CheckBox).Checked Then
        CheckBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255)
    Else
        CheckBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE AFTER KNOWING IT IS A DATAGRID
Have you tried something like this?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="checkbox" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Seen here [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say. It's a datagrid populated from an mdb database. I didn't add any checkboxes.

Comment: Something like this should do it (see updated version) @nikel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your code is for WPF. I edited the question.